# Macro function in R

Tags: r, macros

I'm new to R coming from SAS. I am trying to repeat this code for a set of datasets called mort_1969, mort_1970,..., mort_n. How can I modify it so I don't have to rerun it each time, replacing the year variable?

```
mrt <- read_csv("mort1985.csv")
mrt <- mrt %>%
  rename(nchs_code = countyrs)
crosswalk <- read_csv("crosswalk.csv")
crosswalk <- crosswalk %>%
  select(-X1)
mrt_cw <- left_join(mrt, crosswalk, by = "nchs_code")
mrt_cw1 <- mrt_cw %>%
  filter(cityrs == 999) %>%
  select(fips, racer3) %>%
  mutate(count = 1) %>%
  group_by(fips, racer3) %>%
  summarise(mrt_c = sum(count)) %>%
  mutate(racer3=replace(racer3, racer3==1, "white_pop"),
         racer3=replace(racer3, racer3==2, "black_pop"),
         racer3=replace(racer3, racer3==3, "other_race_pop"))
mrt_cw2 <- pivot_wider(
  data=mrt_cw1,
  names_from = racer3,
  values_from = mrt_c
)
#Convert NAs to 0 and drop original variables
mrt_cw3 <- mrt_cw2 %>%
  mutate(white_m = ifelse(is.na(white_pop), 0, white_pop),
         black_m = ifelse(is.na(black_pop), 0, black_pop),
         other_race_m = ifelse(is.na(other_race_pop), 0, other_race_pop)) %>%
  select(-white_pop, -black_pop, -other_race_pop) %>%
  mutate(total_m = white_m + black_m + other_race_m) 
pop <- read_csv('population_file.csv')

##########################ADD YEAR
pop <- pop %>%
  filter(year == 1985) %>%
  select(-X1, -year)
mrt_cw4 <- left_join(mrt_cw3, pop, by = "fips")
mrt_cw5 <- mrt_cw4 %>%
  mutate(ttl_rate = (total_m/total_pop)*100,
         blk_rate = (black_m/black_pop)*100,
         wht_rate = (white_m/white_pop)*100,
         otr_rate = (other_race_m/other_races_pop)*100) 
mrt_cw6 <- mrt_cw5 %>%
  mutate(high_flag = ifelse(ttl_rate >= 100 | blk_rate >= 100 | 
                              wht_rate >= 100 | otr_rate >= 100, 1, 0))
##########################ADD YEAR
#Save file
write.csv(mrt_cw6, "mort_85.csv")
```

Comment: You can either make R look at the file names in a specific folder/directory ( `list.files('REPLACE PATH')` )and loop over those

Comment: OR you can generate a list of names using `paste0('file_',1980:2022,'.csv')`